# BIRT engine exception while running the report in Tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

I have BIRT 4.2 version framework, while running the application from tomcat server i got `"org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report."`
 exception. But it is working fine through RCP application.Coppied the .rptdesign file in the root of the birt folder in Tomcat, and after that jar file has to be copied to the Tomcat webapps/birt/WEB-INF/lib/ directory.
And mt Stacktrace is

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.handleFatalExceptions(EngineTask.java:2256)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:270)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.run(RunTask.java:86)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runReport(ReportEngineService.java:1325)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:158)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtRunReportActionHandler.__execute(BirtRunReportActionHandler.java:81)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageActionHandler.__checkDocumentExists(BirtGetPageActionHandler.java:58)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.prepareParameters(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:119)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.__execute(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:104)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPage(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:87)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
   at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
   at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
   at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
   at java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.decode(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.String.(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontConfigReader.parseConfig(FontConfigReader.java:35)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory.loadFontMappingConfig(FontMappingManagerFactory.java:419)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory.loadFontMappingConfig(FontMappingManagerFactory.java:378)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory.createFontMappingManager(FontMappingManagerFactory.java:294)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory.getFontMappingManager(FontMappingManagerFactory.java:171)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutContext.getFontManager(LayoutContext.java:356)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.TextAreaLayout.(TextAreaLayout.java:76)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.InlineTextArea.layout(InlineTextArea.java:59)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.startContent(LayoutEngine.java:538)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterAdapter.startText(ContentEmitterAdapter.java:147)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterAdapter.startLabel(ContentEmitterAdapter.java:153)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterUtil.startContent(ContentEmitterUtil.java:65)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.visitContent(LayoutEngine.java:693)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.visitContent(LayoutEngine.java:701)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.startForeign(LayoutEngine.java:736)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterUtil.startContent(ContentEmitterUtil.java:77)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.visitContent(LayoutEngine.java:693)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.visitChildren(LayoutEngine.java:717)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.RegionLayoutEngine.layout(RegionLayoutEngine.java:31)
```

Comment: That's not enough of the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be the root cause:

`Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Consider configuring your Tomcat JVM to increase heap size.

Comment: PS: These two links might help: [Performance tuning the Tomcat JVM](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/11/22/performance-tuning-jvm-running-tomcat) and [JVisualVM Monitoring tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html)